# Incremental backup db2 for i

Tags: backup, backup-strategies, db2-400

Is there a way to do incremental backup on DB2 for i? I want to do something like this  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/c0006069.htm

Answer (score 1):

One method is simply to save your journal receivers.  You can change receivers first, then save the detached recievers.